# How are professional laser shows done

Tags: visible-light, laser

How are professional laser shows done ? I need an explanation of the phenomenon of a laser visible in mid air ,(NOT THE APPARATUS USED which means I don't want the engineering aspect of it,I only want the phenomenon occurring in the air .) How are we able to create a hollow object in mid air . Check this link --https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=F03HeVAa9jY , where you can see hollow object in mid air. What are the physical phenomenon that enables us to see it?

Comment: It can be made visible if there is steam filling the air

Comment: The above two comments plus the below answer are all incorrect. Those graphics you're seeing (like the text, the people, etc) are being projected onto a screen, similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoR0Fvm0mX0) one. It's not obvious because they've mixed it with beam effects, but you can see this to be the case if you pay close attention.

Comment: So 2 people will not see things from different angle, they'll actually see the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing there is the scattering of laser light off of particles in the air that the shows creators are using to allow you to see the image.  They usually have some kind of smoke machine which puts a mist of particles in the air that allow the light to scatter off of it.  The lasers that form the image are focused (in the sense that many lasers converge at that location, or the lasers spend more time illuminating that path, not actual optical focusing) to a particular region in space so that more scattering off of the smoke particles occurs at that physical location.  This is how you end up seeing the images projected in space.

Edit: As was pointed out by lemon, in the example you provided a link to, the laser show here could be projecting everything on to a screen (it seems that if it is, they are doing other things to give it the sense of projection in space, although there are certain elements that seem convincing, without viewing from another angle, its hard to tell in this video).  For the effect that you are curious about though, projecting images with lasers in "mid-air", [fog screens](https://www.laserworld.com/en/laser-show/examples-of-show-laser-applications/laser-projection-on-fogscreen.html) are certainly used in other instances, and create the effect that you mentioned.

Comment: This is incorrect, they are projecting onto a screen.

Comment: In that particular case, I could see how that could be done in conjunction with the outward projecting beams on the smoke to give it a 3D effect, but then the effect would not be the same viewing it from a different place in the crowd, as the outward projecting beams would not line up with the image on the screen at every location in the crowd.  Smoke projection is certainly possible, and maybe thats not what they're doing here, but you said it was not obvious, and it remains not obvious to me unless I could see what it looks like from a different angle.

Comment: But you can see that the light is coming from a single source, whereas you need light from multiple directions to create a 3D spectacle. (You can also see the truncation imposed by the screen in multiple frames)

Comment: I have seen laser shows projected on sprayed water and they have very poor resolution and contrast. The artistic quality is more left to the imagination of the viewer than the actual potential of the technique. One can probably say the same thing about fog.